# How can I retry with a delay in RxJs without using the deprecated retryWhen?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to retry an observable chain with a delay (say, 2 seconds).

There are some similar questions answered with `retryWhen`. But [`retryWhen` seems deprecated](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/retryWhen#deprecation-notes) and I don't want to use it.

- The delay and retry is applicable only if the first try fails
- If all the retries failed, I want to respond with default data.

The following code works, without adding the delay, but how can I add delay into this chain?

```js
of('trigger')
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() => fetchData()),
    retry(5),
    catchError(() => of(returnThisIfRetriesAreFailed))
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

[StackBlitz entry](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-nhzqa8?devToolsHeight=33&file=index.ts)

I tried adding `delay(2000)`, but it does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by

> The delay and retry is applicable only if the first try fails

I couldn't find any condition in the [source code](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/retry.ts) that would limit the `delay` option to be applicable only to the first failed attempt.

So you should be able to pass as a delay either a fixed number or an Observable. For example:

```
of('trigger')
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() => fetchData()),
    retry({count: 5, delay: 2000}),
    catchError(() => of(returnThisIfRetriesAreFailed))
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

If you meant you only want to delay on the first retry, then you could try something like this:

```
of('trigger')
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() => fetchData()),
    retry({count: 5, delay: (_, retryCount) => retryCount === 1 ? timer(2000) : of({})}),
    catchError(() => of(returnThisIfRetriesAreFailed))
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: `retry({count: 5, delay: 2000})` works! I didn't know I can pass an object like that to retry. Seem rxjs [RetryConfig](https://rxjs.dev/RetryConfig) link in [retry docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/retry) seem broken.

Comment: @Wajahath: Here's the [`RetryConfig`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/7.5.5/src/internal/operators/retry.ts#L13) in source.

Comment: You could also add a method to the delay object key and do some other checks.

Comment: All 5 of them getting all at once without delay. I am using it in interceptor.

Answer (score 10):

You could also add a method to the delay object key and do some other checks. I am just pasting a piece of my code so you could get the point.

```
// A custom method to check should retry a request or not

shouldRetry(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    // Example for catching specific error code as well
    if (error.status === 503) {
      return timer(1000); // Adding a timer from RxJS to return observable to delay param.
    }

    throw error;
  }

// Retry operator somewhere in your code
retry({ count: 2, delay: this.shouldRetry })
```

Comment: this is weird to handle the logic condition in the `delay` function but it seems to be the only way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
of('trigger').pipe(
    switchMap(() => fetchData()),
    catchError((err, caught) => caught.pipe(
                    repeat({ count: 1, delay: 2000 }),
                    catchError(() => of(returnThisIfRetriesAreFailed))
              ))
)
.subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: but this will repeat the `fetchData()` even if no error happened...

Comment: @TobiasS. if there is no error, the function passed to catchError will not be called, so why do you say the `fetchData()` will be repeated ?